# Typescript error while implementing ionic's native HTTP interceptor

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic-native-http

I was modifying already working Angular 10 web-app into ionic native app, when I got some CORS issues. As I couldn't change anything on BE, I came across native-HTTP plugin Ionic has.

I followed Angular's instructions on [how to make an interceptor](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses) and this article that explains [how to implement both HttpClient and Ionic's native HTTP](https://manuel-heidrich.dev/blog/an-elegant-way-to-handle-native-http-requests-with-cordova-advanced-http-in-an-ionic-app/), but I run into new issues.

Using the code from article, TS is complaining about this line:

`headers: nativeHttpResponse.headers`

```
(property) headers?: HttpHeaders
Type '{ [key: string]: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'HttpHeaders': headers, normalizedNames, lazyInit, lazyUpdate, and 12 more.ts(2740)
http.d.ts(3406, 9): The expected type comes from property 'headers' which is declared here on type '{ body?: any; headers?: HttpHeaders; status?: number; statusText?: string; url?: string; }'
```

Here's the whole native-http.interceptor.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import {
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpResponse,
} from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable, from } from "rxjs";
import { Platform } from "@ionic/angular";
import { HTTP } from "@ionic-native/http/ngx";

type HttpMethod =
  | "get"
  | "post"
  | "put"
  | "patch"
  | "head"
  | "delete"
  | "upload"
  | "download";

@Injectable()
export class NativeHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private nativeHttp: HTTP, private platform: Platform) {}

  public intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (!this.platform.is("cordova")) {
      return next.handle(request);
    }

    return from(this.handleNativeRequest(request));
  }

  private async handleNativeRequest(
    request: HttpRequest<any>
  ): Promise<HttpResponse<any>> {
    const headerKeys = request.headers.keys();
    const headers = {};

    headerKeys.forEach((key) => {
      headers[key] = request.headers.get(key);
    });

    try {
      await this.platform.ready();

      const method = <HttpMethod>request.method.toLowerCase();

      // console.log(‘— Request url’);
      // console.log(request.url)
      // console.log(‘— Request body’);
      // console.log(request.body);

      const nativeHttpResponse = await this.nativeHttp.sendRequest(
        request.url,
        {
          method: method,
          data: request.body,
          headers: headers,
          serializer: "json",
        }
      );

      let body;

      try {
        body = JSON.parse(nativeHttpResponse.data);
      } catch (error) {
        body = { response: nativeHttpResponse.data };
      }

      const response = new HttpResponse({
        body: body,
        status: nativeHttpResponse.status,
        headers: nativeHttpResponse.headers,  <--------
        url: nativeHttpResponse.url,
      });

      // console.log(‘— Response success’)
      // console.log(response);

      return Promise.resolve(response);
    } catch (error) {
      if (!error.status) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }

      const response = new HttpResponse({
        body: JSON.parse(error.error),
        status: error.status,
        headers: error.headers,
        url: error.url,
      });

      return Promise.reject(response);
    }
  }
}
```

Here's how my `app.module.ts` looks like:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http/ngx';

import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './shared/page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
import { appRoutes } from './app.routes';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    SharedModule,
    CoreModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes
    ),
    IonicModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [HTTP],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Andd here is how my `core.module.ts` (where I want to use interceptor) looks like:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";

import { NativeHttpInterceptor } from "./service/native-http.interceptor";
import { AuthService } from "./service/auth.service";
import { ApiService } from "./service/api.service";
import { AuthGuardService } from "./service/auth-guard.service";
import { AuthInterceptor } from "./service/auth-interceptor";
import { WindowRef } from "./service/window-ref-service";

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, HttpClientModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: NativeHttpInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
    AuthService,
    ApiService,
    AuthGuardService,
    WindowRef,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
export class CoreModule {}
```

Comment: It's just a badly designed [API](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpResponse) so you need to write `new HttpResponse({ headers: new HttpHeaders({...}), ...})`. Designers of such APIs should be castigated.

Comment: @AluanHaddad ah yea, `headers: new HttpHeaders(nativeHttpResponse.headers)` passes TS checks. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular's [`HttpRequest`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpResponse) has an awkwardly designed API. Specifically, its constructor requires an instance of Angular's [`HttpHeaders`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders), instead of accepting an object of headers.

Therefore, the correct code in your case would be

```
const response = new HttpResponse({
  body,
  status: nativeHttpResponse.status,
  headers: new HttpHeaders(nativeHttpResponse.headers),
  url: nativeHttpResponse.url
});
```

I would argue that this is bad API design plain and simple. It deviates from commonly used corresponding APIs such as `fetch`, increases coupling, and is not remotely idiomatic, while forcing you to write boilerplate. By contrast, the Ionic Native team took the right approach by specifying headers as an object.